# VBA MsgBox pop-up according to cell value

Tags: vba, msgbox

I'm trying to set up a spreadsheet to return a message box whenever a cell value is entered, I have the code below which works fine for just 1 cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("D5")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox "Message"
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to have a `MsgBox` pop up whenever either of these 3 are met: `D5="Yes"`, `B5="No"` and `B13="Submit form"`, however I can't make it pop up for more than 1 cell at a given time either writing in one module or 3 separate ones. Each one of the Boxes for each one of those cells should return a different message, i.e., D5="Yes" MsgBox "Please fill out..." or B5="No" MsgBox "Submit Form"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include all the tests in the event sequentially.

This code will also handle more than one cell changing at once (ie `Target` containing more than one cell), which your original code won't

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range

    Set A = Me.Range("D5")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then
        If A = "Yes" Then
            MsgBox "Message for D5"
        End If
    End If

    Set A = Me.Range("B5")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then
        If A = "No" Then
            MsgBox "Message for B5"
        End If
    End If

    Set A = Me.Range("B13")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then
        If A = "Submit form" Then
            MsgBox "Message for B13"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```